# JavaScript not showing up in command

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, package

I'm having trouble understanding what I have to do. I work on a Mac and I'm trying to create a 3d portfolio but for some reason, this is difficult. I am trying to figure out why JavaScript is not showing up on Variants. When I type "npm init vite.js/app" this gives me a Framework and then I choose Vanilla and then Select a variant should show up with JavaScript giving me a Package JSON.

[image]

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Vite changed how they display variants.

Just select `vanilla` if you want to use JavaScript. (not `vanilla-ts`, as that is the TypeScript version)

[Vanilla means "without any modification](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/182520), so in this case, the first "vanilla" means no library added (react, vue, svelte, etc.), and the second section means without TypeScript.

Remember to `cd` into that new app's directory and run `npm install` to install your packages.